# Python How to specify which character to index if there are duplicates

Tags: python, string, list, indexing

So I am doing an exercise for class where I need to print out which characters occur, and where they occur. I did that with the following code:

```
def letterInString(string):
   index = 0
   pos = ""
   stringList = list(string)
   positions = []
   counter = 0
   occurences = {}
   for l in string:
       for x in string:
           if x == l:
               counter += 1
               positions.append(stringList.index(x))
            for item in positions:
                if index == 0:
                    pos = str(positions[index])
                    index += 1
                else:
                    pos = pos + "," + str(positions[index])
                    index += 1
            occurences[l.upper()] = str(counter) + "(" + pos + ")"
            index = 0
            positions = []
        counter = 0
    for key,value in occurences.items():
        print(key + ": " + str(value))

letterInString("hello")
```

The code works just fine for words with no duplicates but when there are duplicates, it doesn't know which letter to index. The last part in my code was just to test certain cases. Please Help!!!

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: you can do this ```[ {"char": i,"position": c} for i,c in enumerate(s)]``` where s="hello"

Comment: right, that's basically my answer

Answer (score 1):

Two methods :

You can do something with dict:

```
data='hello'

dict_1={}
for i,j in enumerate(data):
    if j not in dict_1:
        dict_1[j]=[(i,j)]
    else:
        dict_1[j].append((i,j))


for key,value in dict_1.items():
    if len(value)>1:
        print(value)
```

output:

```
[(2, 'l'), (3, 'l')]
```

second method using defaultdict:

```
import collections

d=collections.defaultdict(list)
for key1,value1 in enumerate(data):
    d[value1].append(key1)

print(d)

print([(key1,value1) for key1,value1 in d.items() if len(value1)>1])
```

output:

```
[('l', [2, 3])]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code may be unnecessarily complicated. How about

```
def analyze(str_):
    data = [(c, str_.count(c), i) for i, c in enumerate(str_)]
    return "\n".join(["{}: count = {}. index = {}".format(*d) for d in data])

print analyze("hello")

# h: count = 1. index = 0
# e: count = 1. index = 1
# l: count = 2. index = 2
# l: count = 2. index = 3
# o: count = 1. index = 4
```

Note well the use of list comprehension, string substitution and the `count` method for strings. You may wish to rewrite this function to return the data in a different format (i.e. not as a string).